# What does lookup <interface name> mean in ip rules?

Tags: linux, ip, routing

Please can someone help me understand ip rules/routing policies in linux?

For instance consider the below example,

```
101:from all to 192.168.0.51 lookup table_custom
190:from all to 10.2.3.4 lookup eth1
```

I understand the rule with priority "101" - from any ip address to 192.168.0.51, lookup the table "table_custom" for the route.

-- But I do not understand the rule "190" - what does lookup an interface mean ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`. `eth1` is a table name in this case (an unusual one). Maybe that is a table which sends all packets through `eth1`. See

```
ip route show table eth1
```

Comment: @user5844653 Then you may accept this answer so that others don't assume that more answers are required: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer